# Create Table in Hive with one file

Tags: hive, create-table, hive-partitions, hiveddl, hive-configuration

I'm creating a new table in Hive using:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS select * from old_table;
```

My problem is that after the table is created, It generates multiple files for each partition - while I want only one file for each partition.

How can I define it in the table?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

There are many possible solutions:

1) Add `distribute by partition key` at the end of your query. Maybe there are many partitions per reducer and each reducer creates files for each partition. This may reduce the number of files and memory consumption as well. `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` setting will define how much data each reducer will process.

2) Simple, quite good if there are not too much data: add `order by` to force single reducer. Or increase `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=500000000;` --500M files. This is for single reducer solution is for not too much data, it will run slow if there are a lot of data.

**If your task is map-only** then better consider options 3-5:

3) If running on mapreduce, **switch-on merge**:

```
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=500000000;  --Size of merged files at the end of the job
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=500000000; --When the average output file size of a job is less than this number, 
--Hive will start an additional map-reduce job to merge the output files into bigger files
```

4) When running on Tez

```
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true; 
set hive.merge.size.per.task=500000000;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=500000000;
```

5) **For ORC files** you can merge files efficiently using this command:
`ALTER TABLE T [PARTITION partition_spec] CONCATENATE;` - for ORC