# How to merge hive partitoned data in one large file?

Tags: hive, hadoop-partitioning, merging-data

I have hive table partitioned on date and hour column. when I load the data i will create 24 files. I want merge this 24files in one file. Can anyone suggest me the solution

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266244/2700344

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to have one single file while inserting the data to your partitioned file then you can have your hive as follows:

- partitioned on date
- bucketed on any one column and have only 1 bucket.

Since your bucket number is 1, all your data will be in the file after insert.

Another way is to merge it using the hdfs commands like below

```
hadoop fs -cat hive_table_data_folder/p* > new_file_name
```