# Outputting hive table to HDFS as a single file

Tags: hive, hdfs

I'm trying to output the contents of a table I have in hive to hdfs as a single csv file, however when I run the code below it splits it into 5 separate files of ~500mb each.  Am I missing something in terms of outputting the results as one single csv file?

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY  "/dl/folder_name"
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from schema.mytable;
```

Comment: Read this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56596869/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `orderby` clause in your select query then Hive will force to run `single reducer` which will create only one file in HDFS directory.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY  "/dl/folder_name"
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from schema.mytable order by <col_name>;
```

**Note:**

If the [number of rows](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-Order-By-with-Limits-query-performance-optimazation/td-p/138457) in the output is too large, the **`single reducer`** could take a very long time to finish.