# How to concatenate small parquet files in HIVE

Tags: hive, concatenation, parquet, partition

How to concatenate small parquet files in HIVE when below are in place.

- Partitions are created dynamically on HIVE table.
- Table is EXTERNAL.

Solution Tried so far but for ORC files which has bug :
For ORC file I was using below command in loop for all partition values and it works fine. But data is lost after concatenation is done which is bug in HIVE 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17280

I am running HIVE query on EMR cluster which is using hive 2.3.3 and this wasn’t fixed until hive 3.0.0

Command Used to achieve this but with ORC file. I need to do so for parquet files.

```
ALTER TABLE HIVE_DB.HIVE_TABLE_NM PARTITION(partition_field_nm ='${partition_value}') CONCATENATE;
```

this is used for ORC file.

Need to do similar concatenation of small parquet files into bigger files.

Comment: Try merge and distribute by solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266244/2700344

Comment: Link given as solution mainly talks if job run on MAP-R based and ORC files. I am looking for concatenating small parquet files present in partitions. Execution engine is TEZ in my case.

Comment: There is also solution for Tez described. Do insert overwrite select from itself using these settings , it should work

Answer (score 3):

Merging the parquet files through Hive is not available at the moment as per my knowledge. Also, "parquet-tools merge" is not recommended since it might create issues with the data/schema.

However, this can be achieved with the help of Impala.

If you want to merge the files in a table by partition wise, then you can create a new table with only the partition data from the existing table with more files in HDFS and drop the partitions from it after that. Steps would like below,

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE tabA LIKE tabB;

INSERT INTO tabB SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE partition_key=1;

ALTER TABLE tabA DROP PARTITION (partition_key=1);

INSERT INTO tabA PARTITION(partition_key=1) select * from tabB;

DROP TABLE tabB;
```

where, 
tabA - original table with more parquet files in HDFS,
tabB - intermediate table created to merge the parquet files of tabA

Comment: Thanks for your help in this regard. I was thinking of using parquet-tools merge but will not go ahead as there are disadvantages. I will see how to use your 2nd way of merging in dynamic partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I schedule something like that once a week on tables that get fragmented due to frequent small data additions.

```
CREATE TABLE tabB LIKE tabA;
INSERT INTO tabB PARTITION (colX = tabA.colX) SELECT col1, col2, colX FROM tabA;
ALTER TABLE tabA RENAME TO tabA_tmp;
ALTER TABLE tabB RENAME TO tabA;
DROP TABLE tabA_tmp;
```

Note that the tabA_tmp operations could be replaced by a single `DROP TABLE tabA` as you build confidence in your  defragmentation script.