# Concatenate all partitions in Hive dynamically partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My hive table is partitioned by date in period of 2 years , and each partition has 200 2mb files in it.

i am able to concatenate running following command
"ALTER TABLE table_name partition (partition_column_name ='2017-12-31') concatenate"

Manually it takes more time to run each query, so is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

**Option-1: `Select and overwrite same hive table:`**

Hive supports **insert overwrite same table**, if you are sure the data inserted in hive table using `insert statements only` (not loading **files through hdfs**) then use this option.

```
hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
hive> Insert overwrite table <partition_table_name> partition(<partition_col>) 
      select * from <db>.<partition_table_name>;
```

You can also use [sort by,distribute by](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75501/orc-creation-best-practices.html) and [these additional params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265339/create-table-in-hive-with-one-file) to control the number of files created in the table.

**Option-2**:**`Using Shell script:`**

```
bash$ cat cnct.hql
alter table default.partitn1 partition(${hiveconf:var1} = '${hiveconf:var2}') concatenate
```

Trigger the above `.hql` script using shell script(for loop)

```
bash$ cat trigg.sh
#!/bin/bash
id=`hive -e "show partitions default.partitn"`
echo "partitions: " $id
for f in $id; do
echo "select query for: " $f
#split the partitions on = then assigning to two variables
IFS="=" read var1 var2 <<< $f
#pass the variables and execute the cnct.hql script
hive --hiveconf var1=$var1 --hiveconf var2=$var2 -f cnct.hql
done
```